# How to show error message if I accidentaly run x86 binary on ARM?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, arm, portability

In my project, we are building application to run on Linux both on x86 and ARM. Accidentally, I have run the x86 binary on ARM, and to my surprise the binary launched - sort of. It wrote one of the string literals to stdout and immediately ended with segfault.

No meaningful message along the lines "This binary cannot be run on this platform" was shown, which is something I was assuming would happen.

Is it technically possible to set my compiler/linker/anything in a way, that the output binary will not be run at all if launched on wrong architecture? Or that some meaningful message will be displayed?

Comment: I assume your ARM system was transparently invoking qemu or something, so the x86 binary was running on an emulated x86 system.  Linux `binfmt` support does allow dispatching to an interpreter based on magic number, allowing stuff like this or running a JVM on java bytecode binaries, WINE on Windows binaries, mono on CLR binaries, etc.  Unlikely that you just got (un)lucky with the CPU natively decoding its contents as ARM machine code.

Comment: TL:DR: we need more info about how your ARM Linux ran the binary.  Maybe use `strace` or `gdb`, and look in your `systemd-binfmt` config to see what it sets up in `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc`.  See also https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html

Comment: within a program in general no, how would that be possible unless the operating systems (even within linux there are differences) had a feature to support this?  you would want to do this outside with a script where the script was the entry point to the program (think google chrome and others).  within that script you could check the architectures of each and bail out as needed.

Comment: granted the scripts, etc are also operating system specific so it only has limited functionality.  at the end of the day just try to run it if it fails then you know you used the wrong one.

Comment: @old_timer: How would you do this if the OS just jumped to the entry point, without any metadata to determine the target ISA?  You write polyglot machine code that jumps to one place if decoded as ARM machine code, and another place if decoded as x86.  [Is it possible to detect the CPU architecture from machine code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38055792) shows one shows an ARM (non-thumb)  vs. x86 example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [FatELF](https://lwn.net/Articles/359070/).

Since that isn't really supported, you could write a shell-script, put your executable's content in there (base64-encoded), and write the correct executable for the correct architecture to /tmp, and if the architecture is not supported, you could display an error message.

That way, you'd have one executable for all Unix/Linux/Mac platforms for all processor architectures, with no dependency on the user making a (wrong) decision.